# How to figure out recent PageRank of websites or any particular page (Homepage)

Tags: google, google-search, pagerank

I have this question because the most recent algorithm changes by Google have affected my website traffic.

I've been wondering why my homepage PageRank has dropped from 6 to 4 (I am not sure exactly). I am not using any special SEO tools like SEOMOZ, Majestic SEO, etc.

So it's quite difficult for me to ensure whether the page rank has been really affected or not. So can anyone please provide any good resource, tact or tricks to address this question?

Comment: I don't know a service that allows you to find out past Pageranks. but for the future, you can use http://www.ruediger.info, because you can: (1) Check several sites at once, (2) Get a link to the results, that you can send to friends/customers, visit every month or even put on your website (3) There are no annoying captchas

There is also one (in german): http://www.pagerank.comlex.de where it is directly possible to send the results to your eMail-address (and thus save them).

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://www.prchecker.info to the check the Google PageRank of any URL.

There is also a suite of free online tools to check other aspects of your site to evaluate SEO readiness here: http://www.seolab.com/webapp/

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for SEOLab.com but it's not address the question. I am still wondering for the tool which can show me my time to time earn or loose page-rank history.

Answer (score 0):

Just found one: http://push2check.com

for stackoverflow you could use: http://push2check.com/stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks guys for you support. But this is the one I just found and looks the perfect solution for the context. Have look- http://www.prtracking.com

Answer (score 0):

PageRank is a numerical representation of a page's link popularity. It is [a published formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) so there is no arguing about how it is derived. This makes it easy to figure out possible causes for this (without exactly knowing why for a particular page).

There are several reasons why a page's ranking would drop and they aren't necessarily bad. This could be due to:

- more pages being included in Google's index
- links to your homepage were removed
- pages with links to your homepage were removed from Google's index
- the PageRank of the pages that link to your homepage has decreased
- the pages that link to your homepage have more links on them

There's even more but you should get where I'm going with this. Since PageRank has little effect on a page's rankings nowadays, and knowing your PageRank history will offer you no useful knowledge, I wouldn't be concerned about this at all.